# Is there a way to print the commands that the shell builtin `source` is calling when sourcing a script?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, shell-builtin

sh, bash, etc. have a `-x` flag that will show you each command that is executing in a script.   This is handy for debugging.

```bsh
$ sh -x my_script.sh

+ case $SOMETHING_DIR in
+ unset SOMETHING_SCRIPT_SOURCE
+ something_process_parameters
+ local SOMETHING_AUTO_MODE
+ SOMETHING_AUTO_MODE=use
+ something_supports_source_options
++ something_echo '[ $# -gt 0 ] && something_echo $1'
++ command printf '%s\n' '[ $# -gt 0 ] && something_echo $1'
++ . /dev/stdin yes
```

Is there a way to do this with `source` ?

```bsh
$ source my_source.sh
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you could use `set -x` (or `set -o xtrace`) to enable tracing in the current shell before sourcing the dot script, and then use `set +x` (or `set +o xtrace`) to disable tracing afterward.

```bsh
set -x
source ./my_source.sh
set +x
```

Note that you might not get the expected output if the script you source sets or unsets the `xtrace` shell option.

Comment: See also: `emulate sh -xc 'source ./my_source.sh'` or `emulate sh -o xtrace -c 'source ./my_source.sh'`  in `zsh` to source the file in `sh` emulation (the `.sh` extension suggests it's in `sh` syntax rather than `zsh` syntax) and with the `xtrace` option enabled. Note that any change to option settings done within `my_source.sh` would be lost afterwards. Also note the `./` prefix to make sure the file is not looked up in `$PATH`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I added a gentle dusting of that to my answer. Thank you!